# ASP.NET MVC Gray out field on checkbox = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm a javascript/jquery beginner.

I'm trying to gray out, disable, and change the background color of a textbox when a checkbox is clicked.  I've had trouble implementing possible solutions I found online.

Heres the code I'm working with:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <span id="errorMsg">
        <%:(ViewData["ErrorMessage"])%>
    </span>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div id="UserName" class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>

            <div id "Password" class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div id="checkBox" class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UseNetworkCreds %>  Use Network Credentials
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UseNetworkCreds)%>
            </div>


            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>

       </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

How do I modify this code to do what I mentioned?  I want the checkbox to gray out/disable the username and password textboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you are *working with/have written so far* I can't see any javascript. To achieve the goal you described in your question you will need to write some javascript code. For example you could subscribe for the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the checkbox and then toggle the `readonly` attribute on the two input fields, something long the lines of:

```
$(function() {
    $('#UseNetworkCreds').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#UserName, #Password').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        } else {
            $('#UserName, #Password').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't a CSS-only solution be possible?

Comment: @bzlm, not that I am aware of. At least it would be possible statically. But I don't think that it will work when you toggle the checkbox. But I am not a designer. Maybe there is some CSS3 wizardry that would allow to do this. Who knows? Conventional javascript on the other hand is guaranteed to work :-)